# Ubuntu 22 Gnome wrong date format

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I'm trying to setup Italian formats in a Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome) with English language, but the date format is not correct everywhere. For example panel clock and Thunderbird are ok (dd/mm/YY), while reminders and LibreOffice still use the US format (mm/dd/YY).

How can I setup the Italian format everywhere? Here you are my locale:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Following a screenshot of my configuration.

[image: Region & Language]